# Good design with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, web

I am a web developer working a web site/system in a very small company and in the angular controller there are statements like this..

```
if ((cover.coverPK == 6 || cover.coverPK == 8 || cover.coverPK == 10 || cover.coverPK == 4) && cover.coverDetailsCompleted > 0) { etc etc
```

Now these coverPKs are the SQL primary IDs to identify different insurance covers.. surely it is bad design to reference IDs like this on the front end, and a new developer joining will have no idea what the 6 is supposed to mean? unless they do a lookup in SQL.

Also, database IDs can change? which will break this code.

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking / What kind of response will help you here?

Comment: I am asking whether that is good practice in Angular  or not?

Comment: It's terrible practice, but how it's related to Angular?

Comment: Well its not angular specific, but it was just a question about good design in general.

Comment: So my main question is, is it is bad practice to refer to primary keys on the front end? and angular is a front end technology. You are right, its terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this magic numbers you can write something like this

```
$scope.typeOfCoverPKs = {"FirstPK": 1, "SecondPk": 2, etc.};
Object.freeze($scope.typeOfCoverPKs);
```

With `Object.freeze()` you can make sure, that to object is not manipulated. And of course you should name the attributes `FirstPK, etc.` with the expressions in the database.

or you can alse generate a service in the backend, which will send you the current states of coverPK.

Than you can write in your `if-Statement`

```
if(cover.coverPK === $scope.typeOfCoverPKs.FirstPK)
{
   //Do something
}
```

Your second question, if database id may change. There is no clear answer to this. It realy depends. For example if your id is the primarykey of a table, it is most unlikely that it will change.

Comment: Thanks, I think i should have constants instead of magic numbers. But also only the backend should be dealing with these IDs not the frontend. Do you agree with that?

Comment: Not completely. If you need this IDs to make decisions in the frontend, you (and the frontend) need to know what an ID means. Dealing with logic for IDs, for example that no duplicate ID is possible and stuff like this, The backend is responsible.